# Why isn't my function getting the result from fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

**I have a function (requestLogin) that calls another function (post) which uses fetch to obtain some JSON from a server.**

**The post function work fine, but doesn't return the JSON object back to requestLogin. Any suggestions appreciated.**

```
function post(path = "", json = "") {

    let url = "/" + path;

    return fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: json,
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log("*** RESULT=");
        console.log(json);
        return json;
    });
}


function requestLogin(path, mobile, pwd) {

    let data = {
        "mobile": mobile,
        "pwd": sha256(pwd)
    }
    let json = JSON.stringify(data);

    post(path, json, (result2) => {
        console.log("*** RESULT2=" + result2);
        if (result2.result === 'ok') {
            console.log("server json return valid result")
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: post has two arguments, but you call it with three? `function post(path = "", json = "")` and `post(path, json, (result2) => {})`

Comment: Your `post()` function returns a promise.  It does NOT accept a callback as the third parameter.  Use the returned promise to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fetch API returns a Promise, which is returned by your post function.

Instead of using a callback to handle the results, you should process the promise returned by the function.

For example:

```
post(path, json).then((result2) => {
  console.log("*** RESULT2=" + result2);
  if (result2.result === 'ok') {
    console.log("server json return valid result")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this process is same as yours but you are using callback in wrong way in `requestLogin` function. you need to access that `callBack` method parameter in post function and pass json result in `callBack` method

```js
function post(path = "", json = "", callBack) {

    let url = "/" + path;

    return fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: json,
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        //passing json result in callBack method instead of returning
        callBack(json);
    });
}


function requestLogin(path, mobile, pwd) {

    let data = {
        "mobile": mobile,
        "pwd": sha256(pwd)
    }
    let json = JSON.stringify(data);

    post(path, json, (result2) => {
        if (result2.result === 'ok') {
            console.log("server json return valid result")
        }
    });
}
```